# How can one resolve synonyms in named-entity recognition?

Tags: nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

In natural language processing, named-entity recognition is the challenge of, well, recognizing named entities such as organizations, places, and most importantly *names*.

There is a major challenge in this though that I call that of *synonymy*: *The Count* and *Dracula* are in fact referring to the same person, but it it possible that this is never discussed directly in the text.

What would be the best algorithm to resolve these synonyms?

---

If there is a feature for this in any Python-based library, I'm eager to be educated.  I'm using NLTK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are describing a problem of [coreference resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreference#Coreference_resolution) and named entity linking. I'm providing separate links as I am not entirely sure which one you meant.

- Coreference: [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml) currently has one of the best implementations, but is in Java. I have used the [python bindings](https://github.com/dasmith/stanford-corenlp-python) and I wasn't too happy- I ended up running all my data through the Stanford pipeline just once, and then loading the processed XML files in python. Obviously, that doesn't work if you have to be processing in real time.
- Named entity linking: Check out [Apache Stanbol](http://stanbol.apache.org/docs/trunk/components/enhancer/engines/namedentitytaggingengine.html) and the links in the following [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747990/how-to-use-dbpedia-to-extract-tags-keywords-from-content).

Comment: running the... ? +1, thanks for the links---they're helping with research